# Can I validate a JWT for claims similar to what is going on with IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions.AllowedScopes

Tags: identityserver4

I know I can write my own filters that inspect claims of a HttpContext.User.Identity and I have a working solution.

I can gate much earlier in the pipeline for scopes using the following;

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
   Authority = "http://localhost:7791",
   RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
   EnableCaching = false,
   AllowedScopes = {"arbitrary"} 
});
```

As with "AllowedScopes" there are some claims that can be viewed by my app as global.
In my explicit case I only allow access_tokens that have been created by a given set of "client_ids".

Something like the following I would find useful to have in my tool set;

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
   Authority = "http://localhost:7791",
   RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
   EnableCaching = false,
   AllowedScopes = {"arbitrary"},
   AllowedClaims = [{"client_id","rock"},{"client_id","paper"},{"client_id","sissor"}]
});
```

My main question would be if this is something that would find a natural home in IdentityServer4 or I could write a middleware to handle it.  Handling claim validity early lets me keep my filters cleaner.

Comment: So is your problem that you have some clients that operate on your 'arbitrary' scope, but you don't want those clients to access your API even though you've said your API requires the 'arbitrary' scope?

Comment: I want to gate on both scopes and claims.  If I can globally gate on the arbitrary scope, than I should be able to view some of my claims as globally gate-able as well.  The UseIdentityServerAuthentication only allows in access_tokens that have the arbitrary scope,  so why not claims as well.  Is scope a claim anyway, of type:scope.  Open it all up!